SIMD 4x4 Matrix Multiplication on Android with C++
I am trying to speed up C++ row-major matrix multiplication on Android, but the SIMD instructions I implemented seem to be far from ideal and they fail to outperform the computation time of a naive implementation (I tested that with Samsung S21 and Xiaomi Poco F1). I'd be really grateful if you could point out what I am doing wrong. Thanks!
Here are minimal representations of my Matrix44f and Vector4f classes:
class alignas(16) Matrix44f {
public:
    Vector4f mRows[4];
};

class alignas(16) Vector4f {
public:
    float x, y, z, w;
};

The SIMD implementation:
Matrix44f operator*(const Matrix44f& pM1, const Matrix44f& pM2)
{
    Matrix44f matRes;
    float32x4_t m2_row0 = vld1q_f32(&pM2.mRows[0][0]);
    float32x4_t m2_row1 = vld1q_f32(&pM2.mRows[1][0]);
    float32x4_t m2_row2 = vld1q_f32(&pM2.mRows[2][0]);
    float32x4_t m2_row3 = vld1q_f32(&pM2.mRows[3][0]);

    float32x4_t m1_row, result;
    for (int i = 0; i < 4; ++i)
    {
        m1_row = vld1q_f32(&pM1.mRows[i][0]);
        result = vmulq_n_f32(m2_row0, vgetq_lane_f32(m1_row, 0));
        result = vfmaq_n_f32(result, m2_row1, vgetq_lane_f32(m1_row, 1));
        result = vfmaq_n_f32(result, m2_row2, vgetq_lane_f32(m1_row, 2));
        result = vfmaq_n_f32(result, m2_row3, vgetq_lane_f32(m1_row, 3));
        vst1q_f32(&matRes.mRows[i][0], result);
    }

   return matRes;
}


Why reinvent a wheel? Have you tried Eigen library?

Thank you for the suggestion. Eigen is indeed a good library, but the code I am writing is a part of an in-house engine and a complete refactor is not a viable solution here.

@Padzak Consider copy-pasting _XM_ARM_NEON_INTRINSICS_ preprocessor branch from XMMatrixMultiply library function, that code uses MIT license: https://github.com/microsoft/DirectXMath/blob/main/Inc/DirectXMathMatrix.inl#L227

@MarekR Eigen is not optimized for small vectors/matrices; the performance is only good for long vectors and large matrices.

You don't need to refactor your entire code to use Eigen: https://godbolt.org/z/re4KEohz9

@Soonts Eigen is especially optimized for small Matrices/Vectors, if their dimensions are known at compile time.

@chtz When size is known in compile time, Eigen is only saving dynamic memory allocations. Computing dot products of 3D vectors, or multiplying 4x4 matrices, is way faster with specialized libraries like DirectXMath. For example, dot product of 3D FP32 vector on AMD64 should compile into a single _mm_dp_ps instruction, Eigen doesn’t do that.

@Soonts, no, Eigen also has specialized code paths for small, fixed size matrices and vectors. There may be gaps in its coverage but it's not like Eigen doesn't do it. Besides, dpps has a measured throughput of one instruction every 4 cycles on current Intel and AMD CPUs according to uops.info. It may not be worth it

@Homer512 For multiplying 4×4 FP32 matrices, performance difference between Eigen and DirectXMath exceeds 1 order of magnitude. Here’s a quick test I just made: https://gist.github.com/Const-me/eb8b77669760486ead570431299bb015
About vdpps, yeah, that instruction is relatively slow. However, when dot product is exactly what you need to compute, a single instruction is still was faster than anything else.

BTW, I don’t think Eigen can possibly do that optimally even if they wanted to. The API is too generic because they support arbitrary sizes of these matrices. OTOH, DirectX::XMVECTOR type is merely a typedef for hardware __m128 or float32x4_t SIMD vectors,  XMMATRIX is a structure of 4 of these.

@Soonts If you know that the result does not alias with the input, you should add a .noalias() for products: https://godbolt.org/z/o14zrhTPK (according to llvm-mca, this would result in 18cycles throughput on a Zen4) -- without that the code is indeed terrible on clang (but ok on gcc). With more clever shuffling it may be possible to (almost) double the throughput on AVX+FMA architectures (though it likely bottlenecks on shuffling at some point). (N.B. Casting a float pointer to a Eigen::Matrix pointer is a guarantee to shot oneself in the foot at some point).

If you first evaluate the product to a temporary, clang is able to join the broadcast instructions to broadcast parameters for AVX512: https://godbolt.org/z/qPvxGExT3 (10.5 cycles throughput on Zen4). (If performance matters, it is always a good idea to inspect the generated code ...)

@chtz Indeed, noalias helped a lot, but the performance difference is still by the factor of 2.2. For Eigen, VC++ produced similar code to your Godbolt link, but it also calls Eigen::DenseBase<Eigen::Matrix<float,4,4,1,4,4> >::innerSize which does nothing.

BTW, note the assembly compiled from Eigen only uses SSE vector registers, it’s the same here on Windows and VC++. OTOH, DirectXMath is leveraging 8-wide AVX SIMD despite the matrices are only 4×4: https://gist.github.com/Const-me/5b4289f052b889a3913b2ff80a1a3e4f

Thank you all for the insightful feedback. The answer was revealed in the disassembly. Apparently, Clang performs vectorization by default, and it turns out that my original implementation was simple enough for the compiler to optimize beyond any further improvements. Consequently, no enhancements were reported for the SIMD implementation, which is, after all, correct.
